# Node js Serial Port Get Response `ERROR` or `OK` sms Modem

Tags: node.js, promise, sms, modem, node-serialport

I am using Wavecom 8 port SMS Modem
My problem is i want to check if there is an error (such as no load balance or no sim inserted) in writing AT commands then it will check another available ports to re send the SMS.

I want to capture only the ERROR or OK output

i used this function

```
function sendSync(port, src) {
  return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
      port.write(src,(err)=>{
        if(err){
          reject(err)
        }
        port.drain()
      });
      port.once('data', (data) => {
        console.log('###############################',data.toString())
          resolve(data.toString());
      });

      port.once('error', (err) => {
        console.log('************************')
          reject(err);
      });
  });
}
```

[Data Recieved from Port](https://i.stack.imgur.com/IuemR.png)

Comment: Your function looks about right. Maybe the issue lies in the way `sendSync() ` is called?

Comment: That function also output the AT command also the confirmation of OK or ERROR I want only the OK or ERROR

Comment: Is it not a matter of interpretation in the caller? If the returned promise settles on its success path, then that's "OK". If it settles on its error path, that's "ERROR".

Answer (score 0):

I am now using serialport 5.0

I solve my problem by creating this function

```
function writeSync(serial,cmd){
  return new Promise(function(resolve,reject){
    serial.write(cmd)
    serial.drain()
    serial.once('data',(data)=>{
      var arr = data.toString()
      var str = arr.split(/\r?\n/);
      //console.log(str[1])
      resolve(str[1])
    })
  })
}
```